# Google Play Developer Console Game Services linked apps don't have OAuth 2.0 client ID

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-oauth

I'm trying to add a linked app in Game Services in the Google Play developer console(GPDC).  I had successfully done it before, but then when I wanted to add another linked app for my debug SHA-1 authorisation. I used the Google Developer Console(GDC) instead to add another OAuth 2.0 Credential.  This is a nono according to the google tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling).

None of my credentials work now.  I keep getting the error message "The application is incorrectly configured..." when signing into google play games.

When I go back to the Google Play Developer Console, and try to add a linked app, it looks like [this](http://postimg.org/image/9esah63vd/).  No SHA-1 option.  Clicking on already linked Apps doesn't help.  No SHA-1 is displayed.  Also, the OAuth2 Client ID from either of the two linked apps on GPDC don't match either of the OAuth 2.0 client IDs on the APIs and Auth\Credentials page on GDC.

I tried deleting the Credentials on GDC.  No change on GPDC.  I added another linked app on GPDC, but then found out I can't delete them, and at the moment I can't change the SHA-1 of them, or see it.

Please help,

Paul

Comment: If the Game Service has been published, to delete it and the linked apps, you'll need to delete the whole project in the Google Developer Console. I suggest you try that and recreate it though the Play Developer Console. You should not need to do anything in the Google Developer Console when re-linking. Also, your second screenshot where you mention "No SHA-1 option" looks fine. You set SHA-1 and create credentials when you hit "Save and Continue".

Comment: Going to Save and Continue doesn't give me an option to set a SHA-1.  Selecting the other two Linked Apps should show me their SHA-1's as well, but it doesn't.

I'll try creating a new project, but it really sucks that I have to do that.  I will have to get all my testers to opt back in, and recreate my store page and whatnot.